# Unity GoogleVR DLLNotFoundException 'gvr'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I have a VR application that has some problems. I use GoogleVR SDK Cardboard. The idea is that if I build with Target Architecture checked ARMv7 and unchecked ARM64, then the application works without problems.
But if I also check ARM64, then in LogCat it gives me a NullReference error.
[LogCat error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzS3p.png)

I re-imported the package, I checked all the plugins, and it seems to be ok, I don't understand why it works on ARMv7, but it doesn't work on ARMv7 + ARM64. Thanks in advance for your help.

[GoogleVR structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06WEq.png)

Comment: what build target is this? iOS or Android, and which version of the SDK are you using? The plugin (unfortunately) doesn't have 64 bit support across the board (only for Android IIRC). if the option is there then make sure to [set the CPU](https://gyazo.com/9073aff2b8c9dbcf986adb64a77c8674) to "ARM64" under Platform settings when selecting the .dll in the editor. Alternateivly (depending on your Unity version) look into the new [XR Plugin Management package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.xr.management.html)

Comment: ok, i use Google VR Android Version 2.0.0 , build target is Android

Comment: I added an image above to show the structure of the GoogleVR package